# how do i add id in this codeigniter select options

Tags: codeigniter

how do i add id in this codeigniter select options

```
echo form_dropdown('selling', $ex_rates);?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [userguide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

> If you would like the opening 
>   to contain additional data, like an id
>   attribute or JavaScript, you can pass
>   it as a string in the fourth
>   parameter:

```
$js = 'id="shirts" onChange="some_function();"';

echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large', $js);
```